# Split number from string in Python

Tags: python, regex

If I would like to split the string from the number of the sentence: `"It was amazing in 2016"`

I use:

```
re.split('\s*((?=\d+))
out: 'It was amazing in', '2016'
```

Now I would like to do the opposite, so if a sentence starts with a number, then followed by a string like: `'2016 was amazing'`

I would like the result to be: `'2016', 'was amazing'`

Comment: You'll benefit from this [tutorial on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html). Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: is using regex a requirement?

Comment: Use look-behind  `re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s*', s)`

Answer (score 5):

Using lookarounds you can use a single regex for both cases:

```
\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+
```

**Code:**

```
>>> str = "It was amazing in 2016"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+', str)
['It was amazing in', '2016']

>>> str = "2016 was amazing"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+', str)
['2016', 'was amazing']
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d)` - Lookbehind that asserts next character is a digit
- `|` - OR
- `(?<=\d)` - Lookbehind that asserts previous character is a digit
- `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespaces

Comment: This regex doesn't work for something like str = 'Surface Pro5' where I hoped it would split at the 5. Would be extremely grateful if you added this scenario too.

Comment: @sachinruk: You may use: `filter(None, re.split(r'(\D+)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(\D+)', str))` OR `re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', str)`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion RegEx is an overkill for that task, so unless you already are using RegEx on your program or it's required (assignment or otherwise), I recommend some string manipulation functions to get what you want.

```
def ends_in_digit(my_string):
    separated = my_string.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    return separated if separated[-1].isdigit() else False

def starts_with_digit(my_string):
    separated = my_string.split(maxsplit=1)
    return separated if separated[0].isdigit() else False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to easily split into digits and non-digits is to match with [`\d+|\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/HB4KVS/2) regex. It will yield chunks with leading/trailing whitespaces though, but they can easily be removed (or kept if that is not important):

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'\d+|\D+')
ss = [ 'It was amazing in 2016', '2016 was amazing']
for s in ss:
    print(r.findall(s)) # to get chunks with leading/trailing whitespace
    print([x.strip() for x in r.findall(s)]) # no  leading/trailing whitespace
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/fWTlJs).